# CRM Unmanaged Sln Deployment Behaviour

Tags: deployment, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Sofar as I know deploying an unmanaged solution should completely wipe & replace all included forms, but this isn’t the behaviour I’m seeing and I’ve been suspicious of the MSDN docs for some time now. I’ve attached some form xml, ripped directly from my (unmanaged) solution which defines 10 fields in a "Product Interest" section. After import you can see in the customisations section that 13 fields remain, yet it seems that some of the form changes have been applied (e.g. change of checkbox to radio button field display) and all schema changes have applied (new fields, mappings, translations, etc..)

The import log file would indicate that everything was imported and overwritten successfully but I do have some maybe-relevant tid-bits to share with you.

- Customisations are owned by 3 different publishers
- Import was not performed in the root business unit
- 100% of existing customisations are already on the unmanaged layer

I am now performing the customisations manually, I’d like to understand this behaviour though so I can tell which changes won’t have applied and plan how I can work around this issue in future. Though in this instance I'm working with a CRM 2011 UR18 client system, I'd like to know if the behaviour is inconsistent across CRM 2013 and 2015 also.

[image: Product Interest Section showing 13 fields]

```
<section showlabel="true" showbar="true" locklevel="0" id="{7ff259a4-27dd-df11-82c4-002481a8e9f0}" IsUserDefined="1" layout="varheight" columns="1111" labelwidth="115" name="Sec01ProductInterestUS" celllabelalignment="Left" celllabelposition="Left" labelid="{51d9f7d2-e17b-4c73-84ec-1c4633a6957c}">
    <labels>
        <label description="Product Interest" languagecode="1033" />
        <label description="Interet du produit" languagecode="1036" />
    </labels>
    <rows>
        <row>
            <cell auto="false" showlabel="true" locklevel="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" id="{7226b58f-b08a-4966-b0ed-ed275c09f05e}" labelid="{404b5467-fc39-4cab-8b3c-66b3b5bbc461}">
                <labels>
                    <label description="Partnership Factoring" languagecode="1033" />
                </labels>
                <control id="ccrm_partnershipfactoring" classid="{B0C6723A-8503-4fd7-BB28-C8A06AC933C2}" datafieldname="ccrm_partnershipfactoring" disabled="false" />
            </cell>
            <cell auto="false" showlabel="true" locklevel="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" id="{ab02e3eb-89fc-4cab-b78d-5f67ebbc1305}" labelid="{196844f4-0890-4bde-8f0c-1f312d0ceda6}">
                <labels>
                    <label description="Fast Track" languagecode="1033" />
                </labels>
                <control id="ccrm_fasttrackus" classid="{B0C6723A-8503-4fd7-BB28-C8A06AC933C2}" datafieldname="ccrm_fasttrackus" disabled="false" />
            </cell>
            <cell auto="false" showlabel="true" locklevel="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" id="{fddf76ad-247f-4d75-a6ba-7da304d8c360}" labelid="{daae06ac-3a88-444c-aaf2-534c3c0d5523}">
                <labels>
                    <label description="Confidential Invoice Discounting" languagecode="1033" />
                </labels>
                <control id="ccrm_confidentialinvoicediscounting" classid="{B0C6723A-8503-4fd7-BB28-C8A06AC933C2}" datafieldname="ccrm_confidentialinvoicediscounting" disabled="false" />
            </cell>
            <cell auto="false" showlabel="true" locklevel="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" id="{05a203dd-4844-4084-936d-99b408a0a934}" labelid="{375bdb4d-ebed-405d-ba81-e259b18c996a}">
                <labels>
                    <label description="Export Factoring" languagecode="1033" />
                </labels>
                <control id="ccrm_exportfactoring" classid="{B0C6723A-8503-4fd7-BB28-C8A06AC933C2}" datafieldname="ccrm_exportfactoring" disabled="false" />
            </cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell auto="false" showlabel="true" locklevel="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" id="{d1733c2a-90bc-411c-817e-edf71f15d20e}" labelid="{3cf8df35-ccdf-40d9-a78d-92a1967be869}">
                <labels>
                    <label description="Notified Invoice Discounting" languagecode="1033" />
                </labels>
                <control id="ccrm_notifiedinvoicediscounting" classid="{B0C6723A-8503-4fd7-BB28-C8A06AC933C2}" datafieldname="ccrm_notifiedinvoicediscounting" disabled="false" />
            </cell>
            <cell auto="false" showlabel="true" locklevel="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" id="{840b3c14-a92b-48f3-b049-ca190f62d5ba}" labelid="{a1795428-c22f-4cdc-9006-16b55051c18d}">
                <labels>
                    <label description="Confidential Invoice Finance" languagecode="1033" />
                </labels>
                <control id="ccrm_confidentialinvoicefinance" classid="{B0C6723A-8503-4fd7-BB28-C8A06AC933C2}" datafieldname="ccrm_confidentialinvoicefinance" disabled="false" />
            </cell>
            <cell auto="false" showlabel="true" locklevel="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" id="{8271f3a4-884d-4c46-bf93-0d711771ac0a}" labelid="{46003870-1fac-45af-a1f2-9af6fe14fb09}">
                <labels>
                    <label description="Full Service Factoring" languagecode="1033" />
                </labels>
                <control id="ccrm_fullservicefactoring" classid="{B0C6723A-8503-4fd7-BB28-C8A06AC933C2}" datafieldname="ccrm_fullservicefactoring" disabled="false" />
            </cell>
            <cell auto="false" showlabel="true" locklevel="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" id="{d057821a-204c-4295-9c7e-baf2a904364d}" labelid="{3ab10852-3812-46e8-b860-6d7b0d39174c}">
                <labels>
                    <label description="Asset Finance Loan" languagecode="1033" />
                </labels>
                <control id="ccrm_assetlend" classid="{B0C6723A-8503-4fd7-BB28-C8A06AC933C2}" datafieldname="ccrm_assetlend" disabled="false" />
            </cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell id="{087c2759-8418-9375-714a-c59b75ccd6dc}" showlabel="true" locklevel="0">
                <labels>
                    <label description="Progress Claim Finance" languagecode="1033" />
                </labels>
                <control id="bfs_constructionfinance" classid="{B0C6723A-8503-4fd7-BB28-C8A06AC933C2}" datafieldname="bfs_constructionfinance" disabled="false" />
            </cell>
            <cell id="{2ae1b646-910e-45e0-db48-34eecbe797a0}" showlabel="true" locklevel="0">
                <labels>
                    <label description="Bad Debt Protection" languagecode="1033" />
                </labels>
                <control id="bfs_baddebtprotection" classid="{B0C6723A-8503-4fd7-BB28-C8A06AC933C2}" datafieldname="bfs_baddebtprotection" disabled="false" />
            </cell>
            <cell id="{64897183-533e-343e-dde3-8271ec4e10d6}" showlabel="false">
                <labels>
                    <label description="" languagecode="1033" />
                </labels>
            </cell>
            <cell id="{78dee79b-1882-0c86-942c-97969e844902}" showlabel="false">
                <labels>
                    <label description="" languagecode="1033" />
                </labels>
            </cell>
        </row>
    </rows>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

CRM Solutions are a very difficult beast to figure out when it comes to what happens upon import.  General rule of thumb is that Unmanaged solutions are additions.  Managed Solutions tend to be an update / replace.  Different types of changes operate in different was as well.  As far as defining columns / forms / views, unmanaged solutions will always be additive.

Comment: By additive do you mean to say that unmanaged solutions also follow the rules for managed solution merger?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Gg309329.aspx

Comment: @Dead.Rabit Pretty much.  The only difference is that for unmanaged, the form definition is merged in and can't be uninstalled like a managed solution.  If you add a field to a form and import that entity as an unmanaged, the field will be added to the form.  If you import another unmanaged solution afterwords, that does not contain the field, the field is not removed.

Comment: Thanks, do you understand why the "Progress Claim Finance" field wasn't added to the section though? from the link above: "Additions to any container will be appended to the end of the container. For example, fields added to a section will be positioned at the end of the section."

Comment: Have tested this in CRM 2013 SP1 - confirms that fields can be removed by unmanaged deployment.